# comparing 2 CSVs on 2 ID columns and writing matches to new csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 files,

orders.csv:

```
OrderNo,OrderDate,LineNo,ShipToAddressNo,ItemCode,QtyOrdered,QtyShipped
528758,1/3/2017,1,1358538,111931,70,70
528791,1/3/2017,10,1254798,110441,300,300
528791,1/3/2017,1,1254798,1029071,10,10
528791,1/3/2017,2,1254798,1033341,10,10
```

canceled.csv:

```
OrderNo,OrderDate,LineNo,ShipToAddressNo,ItemCode,QtyOrdered,QtyShipped
529027,1/4/2017,6,43823775,1029070,1,1
529027,1/4/2017,5,43823775,1029071,1,1
529027,1/4/2017,12,43823775,1038324,1,1
529027,1/4/2017,13,43823775,1039306,1,1
```

Some `OrderNo` on the canceled sheet DO NOT appear on the orders sheet, and furthermore some rows contain an `OrderNo` which DOES appear on the orders sheet but with an `ItemCode` which DOES NOT.

I've imported to Pandas DFs. I am trying to figure out a good way to check cancels.csv against orders.csv on **both**, `OrderNo` & `ItemCode`.

I would then like to write the matching rows (including all other fields) to a new csv, checked.csv.
Alternatively, if i could write all rows to the new file with a new column indicating if it matched or not that would work as well.

Anyone who can offer advice or tips to lead me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

As @Matt L. pointed out, using `iterrows` & `df.loc()` with a dual conditional should get what I want. I've tested this successfully with a small test file, but when running it on the actual file (3,600 rows with around 1,900 expected matches) the result is only 34 rows. Below is the output:

```
,OrderNo,OrderDate,LineNo,ShipToAddressNo,ItemCode,QtyOrdered,QtyShipped
11,528980,1/4/2017,1,1912593,1039823,1,1
29,529222,1/4/2017,2,1254693,1038323,1,1
30,529285,1/4/2017,3,1254692,1041108,1,1
516,532202,1/18/2017,9,2203715,10135131,8,8
651,532699,1/19/2017,1,2060310,10098739,1,1
652,532699,1/19/2017,2,2060310,110441,1,1
726,533083,1/19/2017,7,43824548,10098739,10,10
762,533207,1/19/2017,1,43824564,10098739,234,234
767,533228,1/19/2017,2,1254707,10098739,11,11
779,533248,1/19/2017,1,1642075,10098739,1,1
780,533250,1/19/2017,1,1254733,10098739,9,9
781,533252,1/19/2017,1,1254706,10098739,1,1
782,533254,1/19/2017,1,1751514,10098739,10,10
783,533258,1/19/2017,3,1254711,10098739,7,7
784,533260,1/19/2017,1,1254723,10098739,12,12
786,533320,1/20/2017,4,1254612,10098739,35,35
899,534785,1/26/2017,6,2203715,10135358,19,19
1005,535540,1/30/2017,7,1254612,1040774,5,5
1011,535549,1/30/2017,5,1254612,10135131,3,3
1016,535563,1/30/2017,12,43823870,1040765,4,4
1020,535591,1/30/2017,13,43824564,10135132,30,30
1375,536840,2/3/2017,6,43823585,1041105,5,5
1376,536840,2/3/2017,7,43823585,1041107,3,3
1444,537013,2/3/2017,6,1255628,10137993,1,1
1455,537075,2/3/2017,9,1255617,10135364,2,2
1657,537570,2/6/2017,1,1254612,10135139,1,1
1658,537570,2/6/2017,2,1254612,10135138,3,3
1659,537570,2/6/2017,3,1254612,10135140,1,1
1660,537570,2/6/2017,4,1254612,10135131,1,1
1808,537667,2/6/2017,12,43823870,10137992,2,2
1847,537771,2/7/2017,5,1276705,1041106,4,4
2760,539524,2/13/2017,6,1254798,1038323,10,10
3575,542362,2/23/2017,11,1254612,1041108,2,2
3579,542835,2/23/2017,13,1255235,10137993,5,5
```

The indices of the result indicate that it's iterating through the entire cancels.csv, but only finding 34 rows that have a matching `OrderNo` & `ItemCode`; which is incorrect.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you would like?

Comment: I would like the output file to be structured exactly the same but with **only** rows from canceled.csv which have a corresponding row in orders.csv which contains the same ```OrderNo``` AND ```ItemCode```.

Comment: I am looking into the options of how to match both of the keys. It looks like my best option is the convert the files into dictionaries, compare the two with a for loop, then write matches to the new file. 

I'm currently working on this code and will post once I have something working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `iterrows`, `df.loc()` and a conditional. Note that my `.loc()` query has two conditions so that results have to match both columns. If you are working with larger files, you can gain additional efficiencies by replacing the conditionals with some other type of logic (such as try/except).

```
import pandas as pd
orders_df = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')
canceled_df = pd.read_csv('canceled.csv')

matched = []
for row in canceled_df.iterrows():
    match1 = orders_df.loc[(orders_df['OrderNo'] == row[1]['Order Number']) & (orders_df['ItemCode'] == row[1]["Item Code"])]
    if len(match1) > 0:
        matched.append(row[1])
result = pd.DataFrame(matched)
result.to_csv('result.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you @Matt L.
I have tested it on a small test file with perfect results. However, when I run it on the actual cancels file (3,600 rows with an expected return of around 1,900 matches)  it only returns 34 rows. The indexed of the matches indicate that it is indeed going to through the full file, but only finding a small number of matches.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the output. Any idea of how I can determine what's going wrong with the iterator?

Comment: You can try instructing it to print the matches as it goes to see what it's catching. Also, some of the fields in the two dfs could be different types.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.